# Where to Broadcast Bitcoin Cash Transaction?

Tags: json, web-services, post, bitcoin

Using JSON HTTP POST; what online service do I best use to broadcast a Bitcoin Cash transaction?

I'm looking for the equivalent of https://blockchain.info/pushtx

Comment: Please give more details on what you tried, what you expect as a result and what errors are you encountering.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options to broadcast a transaction for Bitcoin and Bitcoin-Cash. The first, but also the most expensive in terms of time, is to setup a BitcoinABC node on your machine and let it sync. Once that's done you can simply call the `sendrawtransaction` API call and it'll get pushed to other nodes in the network.

The second option is to use Wladimir's [bitcoin-submittx](https://github.com/laanwj/bitcoin-submittx) tool to connect to a number of nodes and submit the transaction to them. This tool was originally written for Bitcoin, but works also for Bitcoin-Cash. It requires a number of node addresses, but you can use the [DNS seeds](https://github.com/Bitcoin-ABC/bitcoin-abc/blob/5a6bac50bb836465b9a22520cd8c1a38218741fa/src/chainparams.cpp#L171) to get some:

```
python2 bitcoin-submittx mainnet ${TXHEX} $(dig seed-abc.bitcoinforks.org)
```

This should submit the TX to some random nodes in the network.

Answer (score 0):

https://rest.bitcoin.com provides a REST API for broadcasting transactions. This BITBOX code example shows how to construct a BCH transaction then broadcast it using rest.bitcoin.com:

https://github.com/Bitcoin-com/bitbox-javascript-sdk/blob/master/examples/applications/wallet/send-bch/send-bch.js

In particular, look at the last few lines of the example:

`` // Broadcast transation to the network
const broadcast = await BITBOX.RawTransactions.sendRawTransaction(hex)
console.log(`Transaction ID: ${broadcast}`) ``

API documentation:
https://developer.bitcoin.com/bitbox/docs/getting-started

If you already have the raw hex and you want a manual way to broadcast it, you can go directly to the endpoint on rest.bitcoin.com, and paste in the hex:
https://rest.bitcoin.com/#/rawtransactions/sendRawTransaction